Huawei Cloud Search(Elasticsearch) gigantic memory usage
We are currently using Huawei Cloud Search vector DB(which is modified Elasticsearch) and my 17M vectors take 130GB of weight from _stats['_all']['total']['store']['size_in_bytes'] even though i used Graph PQ algorithm which should have reduced the memory usage by 90+% according to documentation. Anyone worked with this stack? This is the doc of the tool I am using: https://doc.hcs.huawei.com/usermanual/mrs/mrs_01_1490.html. And this is my mapping:
{"settings": {"index": {"vector": "true","number_of_replicas": 0,"number_of_shards": 3}},"mappings": {"properties": {"vector": {"type": "vector","dimension": 384,"indexing": true,"algorithm": "GRAPH_PQ","metric": "cosine"}}}}

I used quantization and according to the formula from the docs, 60M vectors must occupy around 2GB of memory, however 17M vectors took 131GB of memory and I could not continue writing to index
